# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$rutas' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, html

Estoy tomando un curso de `HTML` y `php` y ahora que estaba haciendo algunos cambios en mi código me aparece el siguiente error:

> **"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$rutas' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\vistas\plantilla.php on line 54"**

Estaba comprobando si faltaba algún punto y coma pero después de varias veces revisar el código, realmente no logro encontrar el problema.

Por favor ayuda, que llevo harto rato metido en lo mismo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!--====  Viewport and Website description  ====-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="title" content="Proyecto eCommerce">
    <meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro eligendi magni perspiciatis 
    amet ratione atque suscipit totam tempora temporibus nam ipsa consequuntur...">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Lore, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet, consectetur, adipisicing, elit">
    <title>Proyecto eCommerce</title>
    <!--====  Website Importing  ====-->
    <?php
        $icono = ControladorPlantilla::ctrEstiloPlantilla();
        echo '<link rel="icon" href="http://localhost/backend/'.$icono["icono"].'">';
        $url = Ruta::ctrRuta();
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/css/plugins/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/css/plantilla.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/css/cabezote.css">
    <script src="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/js/plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
        include "modulos/cabezote.php"
        $rutas = array();
        if(isset($_GET["ruta"])){
            $rutas = explode("/", $_GET["ruta"]);
        }
    ?>
    <script src="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/js/cabezote.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/js/plantilla.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te falta el `;` despues del `include`

Comment: @alanfcm tenías toda la razón, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es de sintaxis y se debe a la falta de un `;` al final de la linea.

La linea en cuestión es la siguiente:

```
 include "modulos/cabezote.php"
```